# Comport inputstream prob

Tags: java

How to get the response from COM PORT.I am using following code but didn't get response.

```
 public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

            int data;
        String r;
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1000];
        try
        {
            int len = 0;
            while ( ( data = inputStream.read()) > -1 )
            {
                buffer[len++] = (byte) data;
            }
            r = new String(buffer,0,len);
            System.out.println("this is input stream msg"+r);
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the SerialPortEvent somewhere? Where is `inputStream` from?

Comment: This is the full code of that prog.

Comment: Dude - that's *not* the "full code of that prog[ram]"!  Your "inputStream" didn't just fall out of the sky.  Neither did your "SerialPortEvent spe".

Comment: You have problems with the code regarding how to read the InputStream, you should look up an example of reading an InputStream into a buffer for how to do that right (there are many examples of that around).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you were trying to *OPEN* the serial port!!!

I hope you're *not* using some old Sun javax.comm library, but using something like RXTX instead:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Anyway, please try rxtx (if you're not already using it), and post back any questions/problems you might encounter.